# test if a collection has exactly one element matching a predicate

Tags: java, assertj

With [Assertj](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/), I can use `anyMatch` to test if a collection has at least one element matching a predicate, e.g.

```
var list = List.of("abc", "xyz")
assertThat(list).anyMatch(element -> element.endsWith("xyz"));
```

But how do I test if a collection has *exactly* one element that matches a predicate?

Answer (score 9):

How about using the filter? https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/blob/9eceff23e5b019af3d09c3e9bbc58126d51c02b6/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.java#L3283

```java
var list = List.of("a", "b", "c!");

assertThat(list)
    .filteredOn(element -> element.endsWith("!"))
    .hasSize(1);
```

Comment: that seems to work, although I would expect there to be a less verbose syntax

Comment: I guess there are lots of possible ways people might assert the collection. Perhaps raise a PR against assertJ with your suggested alternative `hasOneMatch` or similar...?

Comment: Sorry guyz but your solution cannot compile. A lambda expression can only be used to implement a functional interface. However AssertJ Condition is a class: https://github.com/assertj/assertj/blob/9d7c08c9212993a81ed3eb605b771e48e6ae6819/assertj-core/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/Condition.java#L33
Hence, your code must result in a compiler error: `incompatible types: Condition is not a functional interface`

Comment: there is ```filteredOn(Predicate)``` which can be implemented via a lambda